# GitHub Actions: Run step on specific OS

Tags: github-actions

I'm using GitHub Actions to run a workflow on multiple operating systems.

However, there is a specific step that I have to run only on Ubuntu:

```
runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
strategy:
    matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest, macos-latest]
steps:
    - name: Setup Ubuntu
      run : export DISPLAY="127.0.0.1:10.0"
      if: # --> What should be here? <--
```

How can I run steps only on specific operating systems?

Comment: An option would be separating the **jobs** so that you know, clearly, what steps are taken in any of the operating systems.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

You can use either `if: matrix.os == 'NAME_FROM_MATRIX'` or `if: runner.os == 'OS_TYPE'`

For checking matrix context:

`if: matrix.os == 'ubuntu-latest'`

`if: matrix.os == 'windows-latest'`

`if: matrix.os == 'macos-latest'`

For checking runner context:

`if: runner.os == 'Linux'`

`if: runner.os == 'Windows'`

`if: runner.os == 'macOS'`

Related documentation: [runner context](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#runner-context)

**UPDATE**

GitHub provides `RUNNER_OS` variable now, which simplifies checks inside single step:

```yaml
- name:  Install
  run:   |
         if [ "$RUNNER_OS" == "Linux" ]; then
              apt install important_linux_software
         elif [ "$RUNNER_OS" == "Windows" ]; then
              choco install important_windows_software
         else
              echo "$RUNNER_OS not supported"
              exit 1
         fi
  shell: bash
```

This might be better approach for more complex steps, where current OS is just one of many variables.

Comment: With `if: matrix.os == ubuntu-latest` I got:
Unrecognized named-value: 'ubuntu-latest'. Located at position 14 within expression: matrix.os == ubuntu-latest. But `if: runner.os == 'Linux'` worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @yahavi `if matrix.os == 'ubuntu-latest'` should work - you need quotes there, too.

Comment: Also, note it has to be single quotes, double quotes is a syntax error it turns out.

Comment: Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement in Windows environment

Comment: @decades Eh? Bash uses `if [ x ]` or `if [[ x ]]`

Comment: @Samira Eh? Maybe, but it is what is is. The code above produces this error on Windows. Period

Comment: @decades You didn't add `shell: bash` in your step then. Without that line, workflow will use default shell (which is PowerShell on Windows) and you'll get error message you provided. `shell: bash` is **not** for decoration here, but to make sure step will run correctly on **all** platforms. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#using-a-specific-shell

Comment: @Samira Yes, thanks for enlighten me. It works. And does obviously allow to run bash commands on Windows. Cool. Time to get rid of PS

Comment: Perhaps good to know: `runner.os != 'Windows'` works to only run on unix systems (Linux and macOS).

Comment: @Samira shell bash on windows means it's WSL2. So it's not really running on windows in this case. If the CI needs to check that its viability in windows CMD/Powershell then this trick won't work.

Comment: But note, `shell: bash` might work in GitHub Actions, but not necessarily on someone's computer where they might be trying to dev using PowerShell.

Answer (score 8):

Came here via Google search.

In case anyone else is running into issues with line endings with a matrix build, and you want to **avoid unnecessarily setting Git configuration** on Linux and macOS runners, the following will work:

```
  - if: runner.os == 'Windows'
    run: |
      git config --global core.autocrlf false
      git config --global core.eol lf
```